# In a PHP/HTML text input, how do I strip certain parts that I don't want submitted to the database?

Tags: php

When people edit their account on my site, they get confused and think they have to type out all of their steam profile link, e.g. `http://steamcommunity.com/id/######` When all they have to type in the text field is, `#######`, so if they mess up, how do I remove everything from their input, except the `#####` part?

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$lastPart = array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

This will retrieve the last element of the `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str-replace)`("http://steamcommunity.com/id/","",$input);` is one way.

A more robust way would be:

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace)`("@^.*id/@","",$input);`

Comment: Out of the two which one would you suggest also I can't let them link anywhere really, some people might troll and put bad sites like meat spin or something, how can I prevent them from entering any urls?

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/herpderp";
$output = '';

if( preg_match(':/:', $input) ) {
    $output = explode('/', $input);
    if( !empty($output[count($output)-1]) {
        $output = $output[count($output)-1];
    } else {
        // in the case of a trailing slash, use the ~second~ last field
        // ie: http://steamcommunity.com/id/herpderp/
        $output = $output[count($output)-2];
    }
} else {
    $output = $input;
}

echo "SteamID: " . $output;
```

Or simply:

```
if( preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', $input) ) {
    die('Disallowed characters in SteamID. Please enter only your SteamID, and not the full URL.');
}
```

I prefer the second one as it leaves it up to the user to deal with their own incompetence rather than having to continually add lines of code to deal with new and innovative problems users seem to devise. They always strive to prove that any time something is declared 'idiot-proof' the universe just produces a better idiot.